# Como abrir um csv criado no Python sem que abra uma tela de importação?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Já criei um csv em Python de diversas formas como pode ser visto abaixo, mas todas as vezes que abro o arquivo abre a tela de importação conforme abaixo.

Por que isso acontece?

E como posso fazer para que o arquivo abra direto, dentro dos padrões do csv?

Detalhe: estou usando o Libre Office para abrir o arquivo.

Código 1:

```
import csv
csvfile = "arquivo.csv"
f=open(csvfile,'wb') # abre o arquivo para escrita apagando o conteúdo
csv.writer(f, delimiter =' ',quotechar =',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Código 2:

```
import csv

c = csv.writer(open("teste.csv", "w"))
```

Código 3:

```
Arquivo = open(Diretorio + "relatorios/" + nome_arquivo_csv, "a")
            Arquivo.write('\n'  +valores_str + '\t' + medidas_str)
            Arquivo.close()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não acho que é relativo ao Python, mas ao LibreOffice

Comment: Ainda bem que abre, de outra maneira não tinha como saber qual o caracter(s) divisor de colunas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filipe, como comentado acima, não acho que seja um problema relacionado ao python ou a forma como você gera o arquivo, mas sim ao LibreOffice.

De qualquer forma uma possivel solução para isto, seria salvar seu conteudo em um dos formatos  que o LibreOffice suporta sem necessidade de formatação prévia, como por exemplo `xlsx`.

Em uma breve pesquisa, encontrei este [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx), usando a biblioteca `pandas`. Testei com `python 3.6` e funcionou.

```
 import pandas

 data = pandas.read_csv('example.csv')
 writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('example.xlsx')
 to_excel = data.to_excel(writer, index=False)
 writer.save()
```

Para este exemplo, utilizei o seguinte CSV.

```
id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address
1,Aube,Pynner,apynner0@etsy.com,Male,202.161.177.42
2,Em,McFaul,emcfaul1@sohu.com,Male,16.179.223.5
3,Nico,Belford,nbelford2@ehow.com,Male,239.143.91.73
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Att,